# Hunt for a function.

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

I am looking for any *nontrivial* function $f(z): \mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that:

- $f(z)$ is an entire function.
- A $z_p\in\mathbb{C}$ exists for which $\Re(f(z))\geq\Re(f(z_p))~\forall z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $\infty>\Re(f(z_p))>-\infty$.

If you do not have an example, but can give me some strategy on how to look for such a function, please share your thoughts. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Ok, turns out the condition *entire* is too restrictive. Any idea by how much I should relax the restrictions to get the second property (and preferably the same for the imaginary part at the same $z_p$)?

Comment: Doesn't a constant function satisfy all your conditions?

Comment: Good point, let me edit my post to exclude this!

Answer (score 2):

Well, the real part of a holomorphic function is a harmonic function, which satisfies the mean value property, hence the maximum principle. So, if such a $z_p$ exists, then your function is a constant (which clearly does satisfy the requirement).

Comment: Ok! Any idea by how much I should relax the restrictions to get a nontrivial function with second property? (and preferably the same property for imaginary part at the same $z_p$)?

Comment: Well, I am not sure which direction you want to relax the restrictions in...

Comment: Something like - analytic up to a countable set of points?

Answer (score 1):

Such a function must be constant.

Consider $g(z) = \exp(-f(z))$. We have
$$
\left|g(z)\right| = \exp(-\Re(f(z)) \le \exp(-\Re(f(z_p)).
$$

Since $g$ is entire and bounded, it must be constant. Hence $f$ is constant too.

Comment: Ok! Any idea by how much I should relax the restrictions to get a nontrivial function with second property? (and preferably the same property for imaginary part at the same $z_p$)?

Comment: @Kagaratsch By the maximum modulus principle, the point $z_p$ cannot be in the interior of the domain of $f$.

Comment: Then, maybe it is possible to put $z_p=\tilde{\infty}$ on the punctured sphere?